# Declaring arrays local to a function

Tags: arrays, bash, local

I am declaring an array inside a function using the declaration

```
declare -a r
```

I need to employ a local array to the function.

Would I require

```
local declare -a r
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to employ a local array to the function.

The variable is already local. `declare` is *exactly the same* as `local`. The is no difference.

```
declare -a arr
# exactly the same as
local -a arr
```

If you want to visually distinguish that the variable is local, then use `local` keyword.

If you want the variable to be global, use `-g` switch. See bash manual.

> Would I require `local declare -a r`

No, that would declare a variable named `declare`.

Comment: `local` then takes the same parameters that `declare` does.

Comment: Is `declare -a r w` valid for declaring indexed arrays `r` and `w`?

Comment: Yes, that indeed is the conclusion. See bash manual - it literally states that.

Answer (score 1):

`local` replaces `declare`. Use `declare` for global scope and `local` for local scope. But do not use both in the same line.

Comment: `local -a r` is the way to do it.  Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Looks fine. You can try it [online](https://www.shellcheck.net/), if you are unsure.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a

```
local r
r=()
```

or

```
local r
declare -a r
```

or in one go

```
local r=()
```